# Migrar app II7 para outro ambiente iis 7

Tags: iis

possuo um sistema que está hospedado no ambiente IIS7 de uma empresa parceira, porém a parceria está sendo encerrada e preciso migrar esse sistemas para outro ambiente, como posso fazer esse IMPORT de maneira agil? (nunca mexi com IIS, meu foco é Java e o cara que fez essa implantação não está mais na empresa).

O novo ambiente já está montado e está pronto (com o mesmo Windows, mesmo hostname)

desde já grato

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, você precisa transferir a pasta da aplicação para o servidor IIS(*c:\inetpub\wwwroot*) e configurar o caminho no gerenciador do IIS.
Aconselho que dê uma lida: [aqui](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site).

Comment: Uma dúvida, minha aplicação fica fora do C: (ela fica no D:\App\SystemPulse, seria o mesmo processo?

Comment: Você deve hospedar a aplicação na pasta onde se encontra o servidor IIS. No meu caso, aqui está configurado para c:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: Observei que na pasta cujo mandou eu ir, não possui nenhum arquivo.... Apenas o iisstart.htm e algumas pastas vazias

Comment: Você cria uma pasta e os arquivos da aplicação você põe lá. E mais uma vez, aconselho a ler o link que recomendei.